# If $f$ is ergodic, then is $f_n$ ergodic?

Tags: probability, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Question: If $(X,E,f,\mu)$ is ergodic ppt, is $(X,E,f_k,μ)$ also ergodic for any $k \in \Bbb N$?

I believe this to be true; however, I am having difficulty in proving it.

When trying to prove ergodicity for $f_k$, I was trying to show that $\mu(f^{-k} E \Delta E ) = 0$ implies $\mu(E)=0$ but this didn't seem to work.

Comment: $X=\{0,1\}$, $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=0$, $\mu(\{0\})=\mu(\{1\})=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3479570/169085

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no.

Take $X=\{0,1\}$ and $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=0$. This is clearly ergodic. However $f^2$ is the identity map which is not.

More generally: If you aware of the structure of probability measure preserving systems, then you may know that any system $(X,T)$ admits a "Kronecker factor" which we denote by $(Z,S)$ (This factor corresponds to the minimal $\sigma$-algebra on which all the eigenvectors of $T$ are measurable). If $X$ is ergodic, $Z$ can be given the structure of a group and $S$ is a multiplication by an element in the group. (In my example $X=Z$ is the group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and $f$ is a translation by $1$).

One can prove (not so trivial) that $(X,T^n)$ is ergodic for all $n$ implies that $Z$ is a connected group.

Let me say one last thing. If $(X,f)$ is a system such that $(X,f^n)$ is ergodic for all $n$ then $(X,f)$ is called totally ergodic.

Comment: Thank you! Usually systems in examples are, for instance, the unit interval, so I never thought of a finite example.