# Give an example where $\varphi$ is ergodic but $\varphi^2$ is not

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory

I am trying to show that $\varphi^2 = \varphi \circ \varphi$ is ergodic implies that $\varphi$ is ergodic, but not conversely.

My attempt for ergodicity of $\varphi^2 \Rightarrow $ erodicity of $\varphi$ is
$$ P(\varphi^{-2}A) = P(\varphi^{-1}(\varphi^{-1}A))=P(\varphi^{-1} A)=\{0,1\} $$

But for the converse part, I am not sure how to construct a counterexample.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3479570/t-ergodic-but-not-t2?rq=1

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks alot.